# C# dependent comboboxes fire events

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I need some help.
I have 4 comboboxes which depends on each other (building; room; shelf; box).

If I do the SelectedIndexChange of the (first) building combobox, all other comboboxes get the top value of each box and the filter is not only set of the building, it is set over all four comboboxes.

```
    void StartFilter()
    {
        placesRepository = new PlacesRepository();

        cbBuilding.DataSource = null;
        cbBuilding.Items.Clear();
        cbBuilding.DataSource = placesRepository.AllBuilding();
        cbBuilding.DisplayMember = "Building";
        cbBuilding.ValueMember = "BuildingId";

        dgAll.DataSource = placesRepository.AlleStoragePlaces();

    }
    private void cbBuilding_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (cbBuilding.SelectedItem is Places building)
        {
            if (building != null)
            {
                dgAll.DataSource = null;
                dgAll.DataSource = placesRepository.AllStoragePlacesForBuilding(building.BuildingNumber);

                cbRoom.DataSource = null;
                cbRoom.Items.Clear();
                cbRoom.DataSource = placesRepository.AlleRoomsForBuilding(building.BuildingNumber);
                cbRoom.DisplayMember = "Room";
                cbRoom.ValueMember = "RoomNumber";
                if (cbRoom.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    fireEvent = false;
                    cbRoom.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    fireEvent = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void cbRoom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!fireEvent)
            return;
        else
        {
            if (cbRoom.SelectedItem is Places room)
            {
                if (room != null)
                {
                    dgAll.DataSource = null;
                    dgAll.DataSource = placesRepository.AllStorgaePlacesForRoomAndBuilding(room.BuildingNumber, room.RoomNumber);

                    cbShelf.DataSource = null;
                    cbShelf.Items.Clear();
                    cbShelf.DataSource = placesRepository.AllShelfsForRoomAndBuilding(room.BuildingNumber, room.RoomNumber);
                    cbShelf.DisplayMember = "Shelf";
                    cbShelf.ValueMember = "Shelf";
                    if (cbShelf.Items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        fireEvent = false;
                        cbShelf.SelectedIndex = -1;
                        fireEvent = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }
    private void cbShelf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!fireEvent)
            return;
        else
        {
            if (cbShelf.SelectedItem is Places shelf)
            {
                if (shelf != null)
                {
                    dgAll.DataSource = null;
                    dgAll.DataSource = placesRepository.AllStorgaePlacesForShelfRoomAndBuilding(shelf.BuildingNumber, shelf.RoomNumber, shelf.Shelf);

                        ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void cbLageruebersichtFach_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!fireEvent)
            return;
        else
        {
            ....
        }
```

I tried to fix the problem by using the `fireEvent` but this doesn't show any effect.
So, what is wrong?

Comment: Do you work with ASP.NET webforms? a XAML based application ? a Winform application ?

Comment: It's a winform application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Tested try

Setting the `ComboBox.DataSource` property triggers its `SelectedIndexChanged` event, so

```
private void cbBuilding_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    if (cbBuilding.SelectedItem is Places building)
    {
        if (building != null)
        {
            
            dgAll.DataSource = null;
            dgAll.DataSource = placesRepository.AllStoragePlacesForBuilding(building.BuildingNumber);
            
            fireEvent = false; // We don't want to do trigger the evnts down the line yet.

            cbRoom.DataSource = null;
            cbRoom.Items.Clear();
            cbRoom.DataSource = placesRepository.AlleRoomsForBuilding(building.BuildingNumber);
            cbRoom.DisplayMember = "Room";
            cbRoom.ValueMember = "RoomNumber";
            if (cbRoom.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                
                cbRoom.SelectedIndex = -1;
               
            }
            fireEvent = true;// we want events to fire again
        }
    }
}
private void cbRoom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!fireEvent)
    {
        return; 
    }
    else //...
```

This behavior happens on both .NET Framework 4.7.2. and .NET Core 3.1

---

## Didn't work.

### First try

From the sound of it, it looks as if the events are triggered by setting the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex =-1`, but they only execute *after* the first event handler has exited.

The following code doesn't work because ripping the elements off triggers the
`ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged`

```
private void cbBuilding_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    if (cbBuilding.SelectedItem is Places building)
    {
        if (building != null)
        {
            dgAll.DataSource = null;
            dgAll.DataSource = placesRepository.AllStoragePlacesForBuilding(building.BuildingNumber);

            cbRoom.DataSource = null;
            cbRoom.Items.Clear();
            cbRoom.DataSource = placesRepository.AlleRoomsForBuilding(building.BuildingNumber);
            cbRoom.DisplayMember = "Room";
            cbRoom.ValueMember = "RoomNumber";
            if (cbRoom.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                fireEvent = false;
                cbRoom.SelectedIndex = -1;
               // fireEvent = true; // Not yet
            }
        }
    }
}
private void cbRoom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!fireEvent)
    {
        fireEvent = true; // we want events to fire again
        return; 
    }
    else // ...
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still have the same effect ...

Comment: Is there another method to handle dependent comboboxes?

Comment: @Jocelyn I altered my answer, since we missed something on the first try.